# Copy content of Buttons into the textbox?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

So I am trying to program a simple calculator. I have a very simple question. How can I copy the content of a Button into the textbox?
z.B copy Button1 with the content 1 into my TextBox

This is my code:

```
$Taschenrechner = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Taschenrechner.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Taschenrechner.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,600)
$Taschenrechner.Text = "Taschenrechner"

#Titel
$Titel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Titel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,10) 
$Titel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,50) 
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",30,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Titel.Font = $Font
$Titel.Text = "Taschenrechner"
$Titel.Name = "Taschenrechner"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($Titel)

#Textbox
$Textfeld= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$Textfeld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,100) 
$Textfeld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100)
$Textfeld.Width = (300) 
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($Textfeld)

#1
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,120)
$button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button1.Text = "1"
$button1.Name = "1"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button1)

#2
$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,120)
$button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button2.Text = "2"
$button2.Name = "2"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button2)

#3
$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,120)
$button3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button3.Text = "3"
$button3.Name = "3"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button3)

#4
$button4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,170)
$button4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button4.Text = "4"
$button4.Name = "4"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button4)

#5
$button5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,170)
$button5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button5.Text = "5"
$button5.Name = "5"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button5)

#6
$button6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,170)
$button6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button6.Text = "6"
$button6.Name = "6"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button6)

#7
$button7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button7.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,220)
$button7.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button7.Text = "7"
$button7.Name = "7"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button7)

#8
$button8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button8.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,220)
$button8.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button8.Text = "8"
$button8.Name = "8"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button8)

#9
$button9 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button9.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,220)
$button9.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button9.Text = "9"
$button9.Name = "9"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button9)

#0
$button0 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button0.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,270)
$button0.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button0.Text = "0"
$button0.Name = "0"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button0)


[void] $Taschenrechner.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My naive approach:

```
# unchanged code here

#1
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,120)
$button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button1.Text = "1"
$button1.Name = "1"
$button1.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='1'})
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button1)

# change #2 .. #9 analogously to #1 and #0

#0
$button0 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button0.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,270)
$button0.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button0.Text = "0"
$button0.Name = "0"
$button0.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='0'})
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button0)

# unchanged code here
```