# create a calculator with Powershell GUI

Tags: powershell, gui, powershell-ise

So hello guys
Im trying to creat a calculator. So far I have the GUI finished. But i Need some help with the backgroundfunctions. Example: i type on the buttons 5+6. Now when i press "=" it should set the input of the TextBox into a variable and then calculate it out. Has somebody an idea how i can do that. (Im pretty knew to Powershell).
Thanks and sry for my bad Englisch.
Greetings
Sandro

```
   [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

#Platfrom
$Taschenrechner = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Taschenrechner.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Taschenrechner.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(470,400)
$Taschenrechner.Text = "Taschenrechner"

#Titel
$Titel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Titel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,10) 
$Titel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360,50) 
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",30,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Titel.Font = $Font
$Titel.Text = "Taschenrechner"
$Titel.Name = "Taschenrechner"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($Titel)

#Textfeld
$Textfeld= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$Textfeld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,100) 
$Textfeld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100)
$Textfeld.Width = (400) 
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($Textfeld)

#1
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,120)
$button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button1.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='1'})
$button1.Text = "1"
$button1.Name = "1"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button1)

#2
$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,120)
$button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button2.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='2'})
$button2.Text = "2"
$button2.Name = "2"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button2)

#3
$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,120)
$button3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button3.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='3'})
$button3.Text = "3"
$button3.Name = "3"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button3)

#4
$button4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,170)
$button4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button4.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='4'})
$button4.Text = "4"
$button4.Name = "4"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button4)

#5
$button5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,170)
$button5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button5.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='5'})
$button5.Text = "5"
$button5.Name = "5"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button5)

#6
$button6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,170)
$button6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button6.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='6'})
$button6.Text = "6"
$button6.Name = "6"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button6)

#7
$button7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button7.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,220)
$button7.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button7.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='7'})
$button7.Text = "7"
$button7.Name = "7"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button7)

#8
$button8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button8.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,220)
$button8.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button8.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='8'})
$button8.Text = "8"
$button8.Name = "8"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button8)

#9
$button9 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button9.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,220)
$button9.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button9.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='9'})
$button9.Text = "9"
$button9.Name = "9"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button9)

#0
$button0 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button0.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,270)
$button0.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$button0.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='0'})
$button0.Text = "0"
$button0.Name = "0"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($button0)

#Dezimalstelle
$Punkt = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Punkt.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,270)
$Punkt.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Punkt.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='.'})
$Punkt.Text = "."
$Punkt.Name = "."
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($Punkt)

#Gleich
$gleich = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$gleich.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,270)
$gleich.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$gleich.Text = "="
$gleich.Name = "="
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($gleich)

#Durch
$durch = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$durch.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,120)
$durch.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$durch.Text = "/"
$durch.Name = "/"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($durch)

#Mal
$mal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$mal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,170)
$mal.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$mal.Text = "x"
$mal.Name = "x"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($mal)

#Minus
$minus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$minus.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,220)
$minus.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$minus.Text = "-"
$minus.Name = "-"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($minus)

#Plus
$plus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$plus.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,270)
$plus.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$plus.Text = "+"
$plus.Name = "+"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($plus)

[void] $Taschenrechner.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: If you're pulling those stunts with PowerShell just go ahead and write a "real" C# Program. it's going to be less of a headache and using Visual Studio would mean you would have a lot of GUI help for a lot of things (IntelliSense etc.). What you would need to do is bind to the event for the buttons and let the function you bind to the event change the text for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The following improvement of my previous answer to your [almost the same question](https://superuser.com/q/1169962/376602) could help however such patchwork would conduce you to perdition (as well as me). Good luck!

```
Remove-Variable script:Part* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$script:PartialResult = ''
$script:PartOperation = ''

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

#Platfrom
### unchanged code here (cca 110 lines)

#Dezimalstelle
$Punkt = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Punkt.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(225,270)
$Punkt.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Punkt.Add_Click({$Textfeld.Text+='.'})
$Punkt.Text = "."
$Punkt.Name = "."
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($Punkt)

#Gleich
$gleich = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$gleich.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,270)
$gleich.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$gleich.Text = "="
$gleich.Name = "="
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($gleich)

#Durch
$durch = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$durch.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,120)
$durch.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$durch.Text = "/"
$durch.Name = "/"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($durch)

#Mal
$mal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$mal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,170)
$mal.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$mal.Text = "×"
$mal.Name = "*"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($mal)

#Minus
$minus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$minus.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,220)
$minus.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$minus.Text = "-"
$minus.Name = "-"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($minus)

#Plus
$plus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$plus.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,270)
$plus.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$plus.Text = "+"
$plus.Name = "+"
$Taschenrechner.Controls.Add($plus)

Function Operation {
    param([string] $Ope)
### you need to show partial result an operation!!!
    if ( $Textfeld.Text -ne '' ) {
        if ($script:PartialResult -ne '' ) {
            $aux = [string] $script:PartialResult + $script:PartOperation + $script:Textfeld.Text
            $script:PartialResult = [string] $( Invoke-Expression $aux )
        } else {
            $script:PartialResult = $Textfeld.Text
        }
        if ( $Ope -eq '=' ) {
            $Textfeld.Text = '' + [string] $script:PartialResult
            $script:PartialResult = ''
            $script:PartOperation = ''
        } else {
            $Textfeld.Text = ''
            $script:PartOperation = $Ope
        }
    }
}

$gleich.Add_Click( { Operation '=' } )
$mal.   Add_Click( { Operation '*' } )   # Name = "×"
$plus.  Add_Click( { Operation '+' } )   # Name = "+"
$minus. Add_Click( { Operation '-' } )   # Name = "-"
$durch. Add_Click( { Operation '/' } )   # Name = "/"

[void] $Taschenrechner.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hello JosefZ thanks for your answer. Could you explain me what the Funtion Operation exactly is doing?